Metric Filter eror
[INFO] 2024-09-30T11:56:23.860Z    db69b31b-1864-468c-9e8d-0435d0580427    {'Records': [{'eventVersion': '2.1', 'eventSource': 'aws:s3', 'awsRegion': 'ap-south-1', 'eventTime': '2024-09-30T11:56:22.885Z', 'eventName': 'ObjectCreated:Put', 'userIdentity': {'principalId': 'AWS:AROA24OGH3CYSRAKOVTQB:pibit-lossrun-middleware-lambda'}, 'requestParameters': {'sourceIPAddress': '13.233.180.125'}, 'responseElements': {'x-amz-request-id': 'PXTM7CCFS0Y0BFS5', 'x-amz-id-2': 'rZYnRdsnprMGued2oG7tDTBqquMst+tB76x1beuIqZV1D7Z0JbgdS2+mISPwfIV2WEks2j9FDZlzo27djBKAlRk4xxeI6mgO'}, 's3': {'s3SchemaVersion': '1.0', 'configurationId': 's3-new-doc-upload-trigger-event', 'bucket': {'name': 'prod-xxcc-lossrun-middleware-bucket', 'ownerIdentity': {'principalId': 'AWFVTHUZQVQ6X'}, 'arn': 'arn:aws:s3:::prod-pibit-lossrun-middleware-bucket'}, 'object': {'key': 'kinetic/lossrun-docs/2024-09-30/6417434c-7f1b-11ef-ade1-4eaefccf8aee/submit_result/Acord_TEST5689.xlsx', 'size': 27439, 'eTag': '8cb34ea7de75e1a01625cae1d450df20', 'sequencer': '0066FA91E6CF93FBCD'}}}]}
i added

{ $.Records[*].s3.bucket.name = "prod-xxcc-lossrun-middleware-bucket" }
getting no logs found

Help me to find this metric filter

Unfortunately your question does not have enough detail for us to assist you. What are you attempting to do? Which AWS service are you using? What output are you wanting to achieve? Please Edit your Question to add additional information.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
